# Is it possible to autofocus while using the trix gem with simple form on rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, simple-form, autofocus, trix

I'm trying to make the form autofocus on the editor when the page opens, to no avail. This is what the code looks like currently:

```
.row
  .col-md-12= f.input :note, as: :trix_editor
```

Adding `autofocus: true` doesn't change the focus when I load the page, and it would really be awesome if there was a solution to this problem. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/basecamp/trix#creating-an-editor):

> Like an HTML < textarea >, < trix-editor > accepts autofocus and placeholder attributes.

They also appear to be using the autofocus attribute (successfully) on the [trix-editor.org](https://trix-editor.org/) home page.

Are you sure you added the autofocus attribute to the trix-editor element itself?

Comment: I believe so. I used:`.col-md-12= f.input :note, as: :trix_editor, autofocus: true`. Is that what you meant by the "element itself"?

Comment: also, I could make it autofocus if I use `f.trix_editor :note, autofocus: true` but then I don't get clear errors from simple form if I leave it blank.

Comment: If you're using simple_form, you have to explicitly tell it that you want to add an attribute to the element, otherwise it'll interpret it as an option to be used by the input.  Try this: `f.input :note, as: :trix_editor, input_html: { autofocus: true }`